# Safari never jumps into this if condition, Chrome no problem. No Errors logged in both

Tags: javascript, safari

The following code is a part of a larger code. In chrome it does all work well. In Safari however it never jumps into the if conditions shown below. Neither console.log(test1) nor console.log(test2) does show up in Safari.
The Safari Version is 11 and js is of course enabled. 
The version should support classList.contains and innerText ?!! 
What is it that Im missing ? 
Thanks for your help.

```js
            for(var m =0; m<divs.length;m++){

                if( divs[m].classList.contains("activexyz")  && (bereich.contains(divs[m].innerText))){                       
                     divs[m].classList.remove("activexyz"); 
                        console.log("test1");
                }
                else if((!divs[m].classList.contains("activexyz")) && (bereich.contains(divs[m].innerText)) ){      
                    divs[m].classList.add("activexyz");
                        console.log("test2");
                }
            }
```

Comment: So add console.log() lines and figure out what is different

Comment: Thank you that is no help whatsoever.

Comment: Yes the comment is helpful, learning to debug prevents from asking questions. Adding lines like `console.log(m, divs[m].classList.contains("activexyz"), divs[m].innerText, bereich.contains(divs[m].innerText))` gives you insight on what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Also weird that is seems like you are using jQuery, but not actually using it.

Comment: it does log exactly the same . Like I said the if condition is not triggering . What is the insight now ?

Comment: Seem unlikely it logs the same thing if it does not go into the if statement

Comment: Well the issue is here is you need an example that recreates the problem that we can run. Issue is we can only guess at the problem.

Comment: This is all the code that comes before the code shown above. "       var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('boxyc'); " It always logs false on Safari . So apparently innerText or classList or contains is working wrong in Safari. But that I have already suggested....

Comment: If contains is failing with innerText, I am guessing it is retuning additional text. `console.log(escape(divs[m].innerText))` may show extra characters in it. You may want to try textContent instead. Again, this is all just poking at it in the dark with a stick.

Comment: Ok thank you . If I change this " bereich.contains(divs[m].innerText)" to "bereich.contains(divs[m].textContent)" it doesnt work on Chrome anymore. 
But the extra characters might be the problem on safari. 
Can I write it like this "bereich.contains(divs[m].innerText.trim())" ?

Comment: So that was the problem ! Thank you epascarello ! I cant imagine why Chrome would trim it automatically and Safari does not but that was the problem.